# Excel SPILL error by Function UNIQUE Excel 365

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to find unique values ​​in the first table and transfer them to the second table.
I want to do this using the "unique" function.
In the first table I have 2 columns: date and expenses.
In the second table I want to make 2 columns:
a unique date and the amount of expenses for that date.
An error occurs when trying to write using the unique function.
Wherein,
if you write the values ​​not in a table, but in a simple sheet, then there is no such error. I looked for information on the Internet, but did not find an answer to my question.
Thank you for your help.

My second table is definitely empty, I also changed the cell format to Date (day, month, year) format.
I tried to do it first without a table, and then create a table based on the data. Same error

Comment: A Pivot Table would usually be a better way to do this, or Power Query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't spill within a table, so you have to choose just one row of the unique array like this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(UNIQUE(Table1[Date]),ROW()-ROW(Table2[#Headers])),"")
```

to get the date and

```
=IF([@Date]="","",SUMIF(Table1[Date],[@Date],Table1[Expenses]))
```

to get the sum.

[image]